# Export path in .profile on mac

Tags: macos, terminal, profile, .profile

I can't believe there isn't any tutorials about this after googling.
Can someone point me a direction or explain what these lines and variables mean in .profile on mac? How can someone configure them?

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
#export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
#export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
#export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cake/cake/console:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
export PATH=/android-sdks/platform-tools:~/android-sdks/tools:$PATH
export PATH=/Users/android-sdks/platform-tools:/Users/android-sdks/tools:$PATH
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Any line starting with `#` is a comment. `PATH=` sets the value of the `PATH` variable, $PATH expands to the current value, and the `export` at the beginning makes the value available to programs that you run from the terminal.

Let's assume that the initial value of PATH is `/usr/bin:/bin`.

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Replace `$PATH` with the previous value of $PATH. So the above sets `PATH` to

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

Moving forward,

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Again, replace $PATH with the previous value:

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

After

```
export PATH=/android-sdks/platform-tools:~/android-sdks/tools:$PATH
```

we have

```
/android-sdks/platform-tools:~/android-sdks/tools:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

(The `~` is a special token that will be replaced with the path to your home directory, but you should get the picture.)

And finally, after

```
export PATH=/Users/android-sdks/platform-tools:/Users/android-sdks/tools:$PATH
```

we get

```
/Users/android-sdks/platform-tools:/Users/android-sdks/tools:/android-sdks/platform-tools:~/android-sdks/tools:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

`PATH` is used to find commands that you enter on the command line. So if you type `foo`, the shell will look for the names below, in the order specified:

```
/Users/android-sdks/platform-tools/foo
/Users/android-sdks/tools/foo
/android-sdks/platform-tools/foo
~/android-sdks/tools/foo
/opt/local/bin/foo
/opt/local/sbin/foo
/usr/bin/foo
/bin/foo
/usr/local/mysql/bin/foo
```

To see the current value of PATH, run

```
echo $PATH
```

Should you add new directories to the beginning of `PATH`, or to the end? It doesn't always matter, but sometimes it does. It depends on which locations you want the system to check first.

You should add to the beginning if the goal is to search other directories before looking in the default ones. For example, `git` is a utility used to manage source code. If I wanted to install a newer version of `git` in ~/git and use *that* by default, I'd do:

```
export PATH=~/git/bin:$PATH
```

This means that ~/git/bin/git would override /opt/local/bin/git.

On the other hand I might prefer to have the administrator install `git` system-wide. If I want to use my local copy *only* until the administrator makes it available for everyone, then this makes more sense:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/git/bin
```

In this case `~/git/bin/git` would only be used if `/opt/local/bin/git` didn't already exist since `/opt/local/bin` is earlier in the path.

A lot of commands won't exist in more than one place. For example you might write `my-backup-script` and put it on an Apple Time Capsule at `/Volumes/Capsule/scripts`. It's not likely that there would be a command called `my-backup-script` in any other location to conflict. So either of the following commands would let you type `my-backup-script` and run the right script:

```
export PATH=/Volumes/Capsule/scripts:$PATH
```

or

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Volumes/Capsule/scripts
```

Is one better? My advice would be to do the latter. Remember that system will need to search the directories in `$PATH`, in order, for every command that it needs to find. Most commands will be on the local system, so it makes the most sense to put slower network storage at the end of the path.

Comment: So why do some people append to $PATH when clearly you should prepend?

Comment: One should prepend if the goal is to search a specific directory before searching the rest of the places mentioned in `PATH`. If someone chooses to append, they may have had different goals. Updated the answer with some details.

Answer (score 8):

From the [`man` page](http://ss64.com/bash/export.html), `export` simply sets an environment variable.

The `PATH` environment variable tells your Mac where to look for commands that you type on the command line, in the order that it should look. It is a list of paths, delimited by a colon.

The value `$PATH` is the current value of the `PATH` environment variable.

Thus, a line like

```
export PATH=/foo:$PATH
```

prepends `/foo` to the `PATH`

and

```
export PATH=$PATH:/foo
```

appends `/foo` to the `PATH`

Answer (score 5):

Run `man`

And then answer the question as `export`

You can see the current `PATH` value and observe that there are more than one path present.

(mine was `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`)

Observe that `:` represents end of a single path.

You can retrieve this by using `$PATH`

Now when you want to add one more  path to this list then you need to append current path to new path like `/newPath:$PATH` or `$PATH:/newPath`.

And at last for saving it you need to use `export PATH=$PATH:/newPath`.

> Note : This answer is for novice developers.